# Setting jQuery-ui slider handle text value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a number of jQuery buttons and a pair of sliders which set the value of a pair of hidden form inputs the values of which are posted to a python backend which sets the speed of a pair of motors. The front end works well and I have recently tried to add the value for each input to the corresponding slider handle. This works when the slider is moved to change the value but does not change when the value is changed by one of the buttons even though the position of the handle on the slider moves appropriately.

I have included one of the code for buttons and the two sliders below.

```
$("#tright").button({
    classes: {
        "ui-button": "custom-blue"
    }
}).click(function () {
    $("#lspeedv").val("40");
    $("#lspeed").slider("value", 40);
    $("#rspeedv").val("20");
    $("#rspeed").slider("value", 20);
    create_post()
});

// Motor control sliders
$("#lspeed").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    value: 0,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#lspeedv").attr('value', ui.value);
        $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
        create_post()
    },
});

$("#rspeed").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    value: 0,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#rspeedv").attr('value', ui.value);
        $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
        create_post()
    },
});
```

I have attempted to create a variable and place that in the `ui.handle.text( var )` but that did not work, probably because I got the syntax wrong. Also tried using a change function without success. It feels as though it ought to be easily done but a trawl of the internet hasn't turned an answer up hence this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [the docs for the `slide()` event](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide), it says:

> Triggered on every mouse move during slide.

So that callback runs when you use the mouse to slide your handles, but it *won't* run when you change the slider programatically, without using the mouse.

OK so that explains why your code doesn't work, but how do we get it to work?  Let's check the other documented events.  First is `change()`, for which [the docs say](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change):

> Triggered after the user slides a handle, if the value has changed; or if the value is changed programmatically via the value method.

That sounds like what we need.  So let's try it:

```js
$("#tright").click(function () {
    $("#lspeedv").val("40");
    $("#lspeed").slider("value", 40);

    $("#rspeedv").val("20");
    $("#rspeed").slider("value", 20);
});

// motor control sliders
$("#lspeed").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    value: 0,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#lspeedv").attr('value', ui.value);
        $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
        // create_post()
    },
});

$("#rspeed").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    value: 0,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#rspeedv").attr('value', ui.value);
        $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
        // create_post()
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id='lspeed'></div>
<input id="lspeedv">

<div id='rspeed'></div>
<input id="rspeedv">

<button id="tright"> Set to 40 / 20</button>
```

OK that works, but now you've lost the live update of the values.  So maybe we need to run that same code for both `slide()` *and* `change()`?  Let's extract the code into a function we can call, so we don't have to duplicate it.

```
// Function to call on slide() and change() - if we pass in the element
// to operate on, and the ui object, we can use this for both sliders,
// for both events
function update($element, ui) {
    $element.attr('value', ui.value);
    $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
}
```

Now we can use it like:

```
// ... 
change: function (event, ui) {
    update($("#lspeedv"), ui);
},
```

One last thing: `.attr('value', ui.value)` is fine, but if we're working on an `input`, the standard jQuery way to set the value is `.val()`.  You're already using that in the button click handler, why not here?  Let's be consistent and simple:

```
function update($element, ui) {
    $element.val(ui.value);
    $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
}
```

So putting it all together:

```js
$("#tright").click(function () {
    $("#lspeedv").val("40");
    $("#lspeed").slider("value", 40);

    $("#rspeedv").val("20");
    $("#rspeed").slider("value", 20);
});

function update($element, ui) {
    $element.val(ui.value);
    $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
    // create_post()
}

// motor control sliders
$("#lspeed").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    value: 0,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        update($("#lspeedv"), ui);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        update($("#lspeedv"), ui);
    },
});

$("#rspeed").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    value: 0,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        update($("#rspeedv"), ui);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        update($("#rspeedv"), ui);
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id='lspeed'></div>
<input id="lspeedv">

<div id='rspeed'></div>
<input id="rspeedv">

<button id="tright"> Set to 40 / 20</button>
```

Comment: That does indeed work. I had tried changing slide to 'change' but not in addition to slide having seen the mention of programmatic amendments.
Thank you both for the solution and the step by step explanation.